# Can I finish cooking a stuffed pork roast if I turn it off for a while?

Tags: food-safety, pork, roast

I am cooking a pork sirloin stuffed roast. It's been in the oven for 20 minutes but I have to leave the house for no longer then 1 hour and a half. Can I continue to cook it when I get back?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to leave it in the danger zone (40-140F) for longer than a couple hours. It sounds like you'd be cutting it pretty close, especially given that it spent some time in the danger zone before it went in the oven, and will spend some time closer to room temperature once it's done.

So the safe options are things like:

- Reduce the oven temperature as much as possible, so that it doesn't overcook while you're gone, but stays above 140F.
- Finish cooking before leaving, chill, and reheat.